# Перетаскивание графического объекта в ячейки GridLayot Qt

Tags: qt

Как определить, что два графических объекта стоят рядом на графической сцене?
К примеру, я хочу переносить объекты по сцене мышью, но ставить их не в произвольную позицию, а в определенную ячейку GridLayout, как определить, что они стали рядом в соседних ячейках?﻿

Answer (score 1):

У `QGraphicsGridLayout` (если конечно речь именно о нём) имеется метод:

```
QGraphicsLayoutItem *QGraphicsGridLayout::itemAt(int row, int column) const
```

... возвращающий указатель на объект ячейки менеджера размещения. А уже из него можно получить и сам элемент:

```
QGraphicsItem *QGraphicsLayoutItem::graphicsItem()
```

Соседние элементы относительно искомого можно получить тем же способом. Далее просто сравниваете указатели или при помощи иных критериев определяете, что элементы в соседних позициях соответствуют желаемым.